# Best way to insert images in wordpress post for sizing

Tags: wordpress

what is best way to insert images in WordPress post? I mean should I resize by dragging the image after insert? or should I use CSS to control image size?

Answer (score 0):

the best way . use css code . For exp :

```
<img class="size-full wp-image-960 aligncenter" src="image address" alt="Tag Image" width="400" height="272" srcset="image adress 400w, http:image/adress 300w" sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, 400px">
```